# displaying data from data list

Tags: c#, database, display, datalist

As per the instructions I have entered the following code to display my results through the use of a datalist but I have an issue with the parameter 
name

here is the method code

```
     public static DataTable GetSessionByName(string Session_name)
     {
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString = Config.GetConnectionStr();
     conn.Open();
    //Prepare SQL Command with parameter
     string sql = "Select * from Session Where Session_name = 
    @Session_name";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Session_name", Session_name);
    // Create data adapter
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); //Create a DataTable that 
    will store the result of the query
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // this will query your database and 
     return the result to your datatable
    da.Fill(dt);
    //Close connection and release the data adapter
    conn.Close();
    da.Dispose();
    //return the Datatable return dt; 

    return dt;
    }
```

and here is where I try to use the datalist

```
   protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string SearchName = txtSearchName.Text;

    DataTable dt = Class.GetSessionByName(Session_name);

    dlSearch.DataSource = dt;
    dlSearch.DataBind();

    }
```

I am getting the session_name does not exist in the current context when I enter the code in the button

Comment: You have no variable by that name in scope. Did you mean something like `Session["name"]` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean in scope?

Comment: Are you meaning to pass SearchName as the argument for GetSessionByName?

Comment: Scope is a fundamental programming concept. Let's say your neighbor has a television. You can't watch their tv from your house because it is out-of-scope. You have no access to it and probably have no way of knowing it even exits. A variable must be declared in a location that is accessible to a block of code. Your `Session_name` is not even declared. Just because another method has an argument by the same name is irrelevant.

Comment: Charles May, Yes

Comment: CrowCoder so I should just declare a Session_name string?

Comment: If "yes" to Charles' question, then pass `SearchName`: `DataTable dt = Class.GetSessionByName(SearchName);`